# Can I create an integral_constant from a loop variable?

Tags: c++

I try to extract all single blocks from a block matrix. However the BlockMatrixClass from the library I am using only allows access through the following indices:
Dune::index_constant<0>(), Dune::index_constant<1>(),...
They resolve to std::integral_constant<long unsigned int, 0>().

How I can alter the following code to be valid? Without changing the library.

```cpp
for(std::size_t i=0; i<3; i++){
  for(std::size_t j=0; j<3; j++){
    const auto& m = jacobian[Dune::index_constant<i>()][Dune::index_constant<j>()];
  }
}
```

At the moment I get the error

```
error: the value of ‘j’ is not usable in a constant expression
  401 | t auto& m = jacobian[Dune::index_constant<i>()][Dune::index_constant<j>()];
```

Comment: Are you sure you cannot just use `jacobian[i][j]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterating over a compile time sequence is not a completely solved problem since they all rely on various workaround and there is many ways to do it.

My preferred way is to use an index sequence, and unroll it using fold expressions:

Simply define this:

```
template<typename T, T... S, typename F>
constexpr void for_sequence(std::integer_sequence<T, S...>, F&& f) {
    (static_cast<void>(f(std::integral_constant<T, S>{})), ...);
}
```

Then, use it like that:

```
for_sequence(std::make_index_sequence<3>{}, [&](auto i) {
    for_sequence(std::make_index_sequence<3>{}, [&](auto j) {
        const auto& m = jacobian[Dune::index_constant<i>()][Dune::index_constant<j>()];
    });
});
```

The variable `i` and `j` here are integral constants and can be used in template parameters. The actual `std::integer_sequence` you send to the function dictate with what value to instantiate the innermost lambda.

If `jacobian` can use those integral constant directly instead of their own `Dune::index_constant`, you can simply write this:

```
for_sequence(std::make_index_sequence<3>{}, [&](auto i) {
    for_sequence(std::make_index_sequence<3>{}, [&](auto j) {
        const auto& m = jacobian[i][j];
    });
});
```

Comment: Looks solved to me. :P This is the only good solution I know.

Comment: I'm curious; how are both `i` and `j`, which come from the lambda parameters, valid to be used as non-type template arguments here? I know `integral_constant` is convertible as a constant-expression to its underlying value, but I would have thought that `i` and `j` being parameters would have prevented it from being used in the static context of a template instantiation, since the compiler wouldn't necessarily see whether `i` or `j` were constructed as a constant expression.

Comment: @Human-Compiler Notice I used `auto` in the parameter. This is because each "iterations" instantiate the lambda with a different `std::integral_constant` with a different value. Then, since the conversion operator of an integral constant is constexpr and never use `this`, and `i` and `j` are local variables, it can be invoked from the expression `i` at compile time.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot I understood that `auto` means it instantiates each invocation with a different type, but I didn't realize that `constexpr` actually introspected whether `this` was used. Interesting! TIL. I would have assumed non-`static` functions always implicitly assumed a reliance on `this`, regardless of whether it's used (just since that's how member pointers work).

Comment: @Human-Compiler I think the rule is more general, and affects any parameter of a `constexpr` function.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I will consider it solved when we'll get `template for`

Comment: Thank you for this great answer, it's a readable, understandable and scalable solution, and it also worked with jacobian[i][j] :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>

template <size_t index, size_t end>
void for_loop () {
    if constexpr (index == end) {
        return;
    }

    constexpr size_t i = index / 3;
    constexpr size_t j = index % 3;
    const auto& m = jacobian[Dune::index_constant<i>()][Dune::index_constant<j>()];

    impl<index + 1, end>();
}

template <size_t end>
void for_loop_to() {
    for_loop<0, end>();
}

int main ()
{
    for_loop_to<9>();
}
```

Would something like this work for a constexpr for loop type thing? This works for C++17 (since it requires the `constexpr if`) but more verbose versions would be implemented for earlier c++ versions. Also I didn't plumb `jacobian` through to the inner function, but you could do that with a struct wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

You can unroll the loops:

```
const auto& m = jacobian[Dune::index_constant<0>()][Dune::index_constant<0>()];
const auto& m = jacobian[Dune::index_constant<0>()][Dune::index_constant<1>()];
const auto& m = jacobian[Dune::index_constant<0>()][Dune::index_constant<2>()];

const auto& m = jacobian[Dune::index_constant<1>()][Dune::index_constant<0>()];
const auto& m = jacobian[Dune::index_constant<1>()][Dune::index_constant<1>()];
const auto& m = jacobian[Dune::index_constant<1>()][Dune::index_constant<2>()];

const auto& m = jacobian[Dune::index_constant<2>()][Dune::index_constant<0>()];
const auto& m = jacobian[Dune::index_constant<2>()][Dune::index_constant<1>()];
const auto& m = jacobian[Dune::index_constant<2>()][Dune::index_constant<2>()];
```

If thats not an option you can apply some form of compile time for:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template <template<size_t> class F,size_t ... I>
void for_impl(std::index_sequence<I...>){
    (F<I>{}(),...);
}

template <template<size_t> class F,std::size_t N,typename Indices = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
void for_(){
    for_impl<F>(Indices{});
}

template <size_t i>
struct foo{
    void operator()() {
        std::cout << i << "\n";
    }
};


int main() {
    for_<foo,5>();
}
```

Here only outlined for one loop. I wasn't sure if you need both loops unrolled at compile time. In the example `foo` is the template you would wrap the loop body inside.